# update with ranking picking tuples

Tags: mysql, date, inner-join, ranking

I have a table ProductPrice

```
INSERT INTO ProductPrice
(
ProductId,
EffectiveDt,
InactiveDt,
Price
)
```

i have dates that have gaps between them
or overlap

what i have so far it the table ranked by the earliest effective date being the 1 first and then by the product id

this uses

```
SELECT 
    pp.ProductId,
    pp.EffectiveDt,
    pp.InactiveDt, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pp.ProductId ORDER BY pp.EffectiveDt ASC) AS         RankByDate
INTO
    #ProductrankByDate
FROM 
    ProductPrice pp
ORDER BY 
    pp.ProductId
```

now what i want to do is an update

were it takes the InactiveDt and updates it with the next ranks effectiveDt

so

```
01/07/2012 , 10/07/2012
15/07/2012 , 20/07/2012
```

and

```
01/07/2012 , 10/07/2012
08/07/2012 , 20/07/2012
```

would become

```
01/07/2012 , 14/07/2012
15/07/2012 , 20/07/2012
```

and

```
01/07/2012 , 07/07/2012
08/07/2012 , 20/07/2012
```

I Have so far

```
UPDATE pp
SET 
    pp.InactiveDt = DATEADD(DAY, -1, pdb.EffectiveDt)
FROM 
    #ProductrankByDate AS pp
INNER JOIN 
    #ProductrankByDate AS pdb 
ON 
    pp.ProductId  = pdb.ProductId
WHERE
    pp.RankByDate = pdb.RankByDate + 1
AND pp.ProductId  = pdb.ProductId
```

but obviously this doesn't work so any help on modifying this or a new statement would be lots of help thanks

Comment: I read this a couple of times, and it's not exactly clear to me what it is you're trying to accomplish. I assume you have a product price that changes after a certain date? Wouldn't it be much easier to make a new entry in your database, and use a select query that incorporates the date?

Comment: this isn't my database so i can't do stuff like change the schema or add columns ect ect, but i need everything to be update and working smoothley and i can't do anything manual as there are actually million of records

Comment: That doesn't answer my question :) Actually, it raises one more: if your database contains millions of records, how was this done previously? I assume this is not the first time dates have to be changed?

Comment: they have corrupt over time by a difference piece of software which i don't have access too. but i have solved the problem now

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working all i had to do is move the +1 behind the pp.RankByDate instead of being the pbd.RankByDate

```
UPDATE pp
SET 
    pp.InactiveDt = DATEADD(DAY, -1, pdb.EffectiveDt)
FROM 
    #ProductrankByDate AS pp
INNER JOIN 
    #ProductrankByDate AS pdb 
ON 
    pp.ProductId      = pdb.ProductId
WHERE
    pp.RankByDate + 1 = pdb.RankByDate
AND pp.ProductId      = pdb.ProductId
```